# Как использовать хеш таблицу для хранения данных?

Tags: c++

нашел статью на хабре про самую быструю хеш таблицу, называется flat hash map. По словам автора, работать с ней точно так же как и с std::unordered_map, но я вообще не работал с unordered_map, а flat_hash_map мне не совсем понятен.

Кому не сложно, покажите как его использовать в нескольких примерах.
В С++ не так давно, но мне необходимо изучить flat_hash_map
В гугле вообще никаких примеров нет про эту хеш таблицу

Ссылка на flat_hash_map
https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map

Ссыка на статью из хабра
https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/323242/

Кстати, стоит ли ее вообще использовать и в каких случаях опасаться коллизий?

Comment: Вы бы хоть ссылку на статью бросили...

Comment: извините, забыл добавить. Обновил пост

Comment: Читаете, как использовать `unordered_map`. Учитесь, применяете. Потом дописываете `#include "unordered_map.hpp"`, а вместо `unordered_map` пишете `ska::unordered_map`. Ничего более не меняя - и получаете выигрыш во времени. Небольшой, но вроде действительно есть - типа 0,33 секунды против 0,40 (в простейшем моем эксперименте). Как именно работать с `unordered_map` - этого и в Интернете, и в книгах полно... "Опасаться коллизий" - они все равно всегда будут :) Для своих типов просто подбирайте хорошие хэш-функции, для стандартных типов стандартные должны быть неплохими :)

Comment: На более сложных типах и больших размерах, кстати, в VC++2017 выигрыш съедается...

Comment: Судя по статье, автор сосредоточен на хранении чисел. Если вы собираетесь хранить что-то более сложное - стоит проверить производительность для вашего конкретного случая.Описание работы с `std::unordered_map` есть [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Ну и если будете измерять производительность, посмотрите еще в сторону `boost::flat_map` (сортированный массив с логарифмическим поиском).

Comment: Мне нужно хранить от char, int
Я вообще думал использовать Redis, но там уходит 0,011 времени на вытаскивание данных

Comment: `map<char,int>`?! Да не морочьте тогда голову! `int m[256]` или, если очень хочется - `array<int,256>` - идеально быстрое и очень небольшое по памяти решение!

Comment: Я собираюсь хранить данные игроков, я же не могу на каждого игрока выделять постоянно map 
Представьте что у нас 100 игроков и у каждого есть персонаж, которые хранит в себе данные: уровень, опыт, силу и т.п. 
Что использовать для хранения данных и быстрому обращению к ним?

Comment: Обращения по какому полю? По номеру игрока? Тогда 200% - просто массив структур. Если нужен поиск... Да при таком количестве - 100 штук - линейный поиск вполне достойное решение :)

Comment: 100 - это образно, обращение будет через сокет ID.
Учитывая, что у каждого игрока, кто подключается к сервере выдается ID сокета, то мы можем использовать его как идентификатор в структуре где будем хранить данные игрока. 
Собственно, какое решение подойдет лучше всего чтобы можно было хранить данные пользователя и быстро их получать. Игроков может быть от 1 до 10 000 к примеру.

Comment: Я бы прислушался совету  Harry.   Не создавайте искусственные сложности...

Comment: Мне припоминается, что эти ID - будут до 65536? или я ошибаюсь? Тогда если для каждого игрока отпустить по 128 байт для круглого счета, имеем память 8 мегабайт. Для современного компьютера - плюнуть и растереть :) Зато мгновенный доступ. Если больше - ну, тогда хранить таблицу указателей, пусть по 8 байт (64-разрядный) - итого полмегабайта на таблицу, цена снижения памяти - косвенное обращение. Скорость - максимальная.

Comment: Хотите сказать, что это экономия на спичках?

Comment: Использование `unordered_map`? Думаю, да. Тем более что накладные расходы там явно будут высокими, как по памяти, так и по времени. И вообще - **Premature optimization is the root of all evil** *(с) Donald Knuth* :)

Comment: Ладно, спасибо.
Кстати, вопрос не по теме задам, пока вы здесь.
Могу ли я использовать Redis как замена mysql для хранения данных на постоянной основе? Думал использовать режим AOF в Redis для сохранения данных на жесткий диск каждую секунду

Comment: Это уже вопрос не ко мне :(